# Java not allowed to call recursive method with generic type?

Tags: java, generics, types

```
public class ResourceAssembler<T extends BasedEntity> {


    public Resource<T> toResource(T  entity) {
       ExtendsBasedEntity e = getExtendsBasedEntity();
       toResource(e); //<----compile error
       //some other code
    }
}

public class ExtendsBasedEntity extends BasedEntity{}
```

But if you call it from the outside its fine

```
//some other class
new ResourceAssembler<ExtendsBasedEntity>().toResource(new ExtendsBasedEntity())
```

Why?

```
Error:(28, 25) java: incompatible types: spring.BasedEntity cannot be converted to T
```

Comment: share `toResource` signature

Comment: thats the signature, right there. public Resource<T> toResource(T  entity)

Comment: When called from inside `#toResource` there is no guarantee that `T` will be `ExtendsBasedEntity`.

Comment: why? whats the difference to the compiler from inside and outside?

Comment: The difference is that, when inside the class, the `T` unknown, except for the fact it will be **some subtype** of `BasedEntity`.

Comment: so how do you fix it from the inside?

Comment: Depends on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I want it to compile

Comment: As per class "ResourceAssembler<T extends BasedEntity" declaration,  T should be subtype of BasedEntity, Can you share ExtendsBasedEntity class declaration?

Comment: well theres no assuming, Im literally creating the object in there myself.

Comment: What is the definition of `getExtendsBasedEntity()`? Where does it get the object to return? Can it return `T` instead?

Answer (score 2):

`T` may not be `ExtendsBasedEntity`, but some other subtype of `BaseEntity`, hence the compile error.

One way to "fix" the problem, is to use a *type token*

```
public class ResourceAssembler<T extends BasedEntity> {

    private final Class<T> type;

    public ResourceAssembler(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Resource<T> toResource(T  entity) {
       toResource(type.newInstance());
       //some other code
    }
}
```

Assuming that works for you.

Comment: In my real code, its actually not new object but gotten from another class. In that case how do I solve that? Edited question

Comment: @Bohemian can you tell me some ways in which this approach can throw in an `InstantiationException`? Or is it possible for it to throw?

Comment: @Shankha057 `newInstance()` will throw an `InstantiationException` if there's no default constructor.

Comment: @erotsppa You can't "solve" it. You can't know what the actual type is a runtime unless you have a type token is some form, so you can't use an arbitrary subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Let's create two classes extending `BasedEntity` and call them `EBE1` and `EBE2`.
Now you create a `ResourceAssembly` object using `EBE1` as the type parameter. But let's say that in the implementation of the `toResource` method you do something like `return toResource(new EBE2());`.

So the return type of `toResource()` is becoming `Resource<EBE2>` but that is wrong because according to the structure you should return `Resource<EBE1>`. And that's why the compile time error. And type safety instincts of Java kicks in.

If you want to do return a generic for the `toResource` method then you either have to pass in the `entity` object down as it is or change it to the concrete type that you are initializing it within and not use generic (although I don't know why would anyone use the second option, but it's a "solution" to make it "compile").

Also, on the outside when you declare it. You are not specifying the type parameter for `ResourceAssembly` and hence it's a raw one. Try to do it with a type param. You will have red squiggly lines there as well.

Here is an example:

```
static class Resource<T> {

}

static class BasedEntity {

}

static class ExtendsBasedEntity1 extends BasedEntity {

}

static class ExtendsBasedEntity2 extends BasedEntity {

}
static public class ResourceAssembler<T extends BasedEntity> {


    public Resource<T> toResource(T entity) {
        return toResource(new ExtendsBasedEntity1()); //<----compile error
    }
}  



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ResourceAssembler<ExtendsBasedEntity1>().toResource(new ExtendsBasedEntity1()); // <---- No errors or warnings. This is valid and legal
        new ResourceAssembler<ExtendsBasedEntity2>().toResource(new ExtendsBasedEntity1()); // <----- red squiggly lines here
        new ResourceAssembler().toResource(new ExtendsBasedEntity2()); // <--compiler warning about raw types but no error
    }
```

If you anyhow need to make it work the way you want it to, then instead of returning `Resource<T>`, return `Resource<ExtendsBasedEntity>` because you are recursing inside a generic method and looks like you need an object of concrete type to go in as the parameter for the recursive call. So it would make sense to do so.
Or else, go with [@Bohemian's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58758568/6601614) and make sure that in the class declaration of the type that you are using, there is a no-args constructor or else you will be having `InstantiationException`.

Comment: I need it to work inside the method, to be able to call itself. Do you know how? thanks